# SQL Server 2008 Return Part of a Line between start and end measurements

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, spatial

Is there a spatial function that will return part of a line between a start and end measurement?  I have a table that contains lines using Geometry data type - call it "Roads".  I have another table that contains "From" and "To" columns as well as a line identifier - call it "Pavement".

Roads:
RoadID -- Geometry
1 -- LineGeom
2 -- LineGeom
3 -- LineGeom

Pavement:
RoadID -- From -- To
1 -- 0 -- 10
2 -- 25 -- 120
3 -- 10 -- 450

Using the example above, I would want a query that returns that portion of RoadID 1 between 0 and 10 metres, that portion of RoadID 2 between 25 and 120 metres, and that portion of RoadID 3 between 10 and 450 metres.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Spatial SQL but this guys sure does 
[The GIS Doctor](http://www.gisdoctor.com/site/2012/01/30/spatial-sql-geographer-%E2%80%93-part-3-%E2%80%93-basic-spatial-sql-scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Spatial does not natively support linear referencing.  You would probably be better served using something someone like Esri or Intergraph has done for this.  That being said you could create a homebrew solution that would do the same thing.

You could loop through each of the vertices, track distance from the first, interpolate position for distance you want, and draw the new line.
I haven't test this, I just wrote it, so it may need some tweaking to actually work:

```
DECLARE @g GEOMETRY = (SELECT TOP 1 Road FROM Roads)

DECLARE @BeginMeasure DECIMAL(10,5) = 1
DECLARE @EndMeasure DECIMAL(10,5) = 5

DECLARE @ReturnLine GEOGRAPHY = NULL

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @CumulativeDistance DECIMAL(10,5) = 0

WHILE @i < @g.STNumPoints()
BEGIN
  IF @BeginMeasure BETWEEN @CumulativeDistance AND @CumulativeDistance + @g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))
  BEGIN
    SET @ReturnLine = GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
                                                CAST(
                                                  (@g.STPointN(@i+1).STX - @g.STPointN(@i).STX) -- Change in X
                                                  *((@BeginMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                                AS VARCHAR(10)) --X
                                                + ' ' +
                                                CAST(
                                                  (@g.STPointN(@i+1).STY - @g.STPointN(@i).STY) -- Change in Y
                                                  *((@BeginMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                                AS VARCHAR(10)) --Y
                                                 + ')',0)
  END

  IF @ReturnLine IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    IF @ReturnLine.STGeometryType() = 'Point'
    BEGIN
      IF @EndMeasure BETWEEN @CumulativeDistance AND @CumulativeDistance + @g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))
      BEGIN
        SET @ReturnLine = @ReturnLine.ShortestLineTo(
          GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
                                    CAST(
                                      (@g.STPointN(@i).STX - @g.STPointN(@i-1).STX) -- Change in X
                                      *((@BeginMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i-1).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                    AS VARCHAR(10)) --X
                                    + ' ' +
                                    CAST(
                                      (@g.STPointN(@i).STY - @g.STPointN(@i-1).STY) -- Change in Y
                                      *((@BeginMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i-1).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                    AS VARCHAR(10)) --Y
                                      + ')',0)
        )
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        SET @ReturnLine = @ReturnLine.ShortestLineTo(@g.STPointN(@i))
      END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      IF @EndMeasure BETWEEN @CumulativeDistance AND @CumulativeDistance + @g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))
      BEGIN
        SET @ReturnLine = @ReturnLine.STUnion(@g.STPointN(@i-1).ShortestLineTo(     
          GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
                                    CAST(
                                      (@g.STPointN(@i).STX - @g.STPointN(@i-1).STX) -- Change in X
                                      *((@EndMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i-1).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                    AS VARCHAR(10)) --X
                                    + ' ' +
                                    CAST(
                                      (@g.STPointN(@i).STY - @g.STPointN(@i-1).STY) -- Change in Y
                                      *((@EndMeasure-@CumulativeDistance)/@g.STPointN(@i-1).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i))) --Percent Change in Distance,
                                    AS VARCHAR(10)) --Y
                                      + ')',0)
        ))
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        SET @ReturnLine = @ReturnLine.STUnion(@g.STPointN(@i-1).ShortestLineTo(@g.STPointN(@i)))
      END
    END
  END 

  SET @CumulativeDistance = @CumulativeDistance + @g.STPointN(@i).STDistance(@g.STPointN(@i+1))
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @ReturnLine
```